# Determine who/what called Set Property

Tags: c#, .net, properties, set, inotifypropertychanged

I am trying to determine what control called a `Set property`.  Say textbox *Pet* is bound to a Property.  I am using `INotifyPropertyChanged` but I am wondering if there is a way to get the actual control.

The `sender` in my `PropertyChanged Event` is the **Class** containing the properties and not the **control** that originally kicked of the chain of events that lead to the Event being raised.

Is this possible?  Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 2):

you could go for capturing the `StackTrace`, eg.

```
var methodBase = new StackTrace().GetFrame(1/* depends on your depth*/).GetMethod();
var reflecedType = methodBase.ReflectedType;
var methodName = methodBase.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to know which control did something, just attach an event to the control and handle that event in the view's codebehind.

The INPC model object that's having bindings applied to it should be view-agnostic...

This applies to WPF or Winforms, but out of curiousity, which are you using?

Comment: winform and I see what you are saying, I think.  It would tie my object too tightly I suppose.